# Get total td values with Angular JS

Tags: angularjs

I'm trying to add total price with using Angular JS.

```
<table>
    <tr>
      <th>Price</th>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td>10</td>
    </tr>
<tr>
      <td>20</td>
    </tr>
<tr>
      <td>30</td>
    </tr>
<tr>
      <td>40</td>
    </tr>
<tr>
      <td>50</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Total Price</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Did any of the below answers help, Suiwal?

Comment: yes it's work! thank you

Comment: Great. Please consider upvoting anything you found helpful, and if there is an answer you like the most, "accept" it. To do so, click the tick mark to the left of that answer, to mark it as the solution. Thanks!

Comment: Downvoted, with apologies (see above).

Answer (score 1):

This is a possible way of achieving what you asked for using ng-init:

```
<table ng-init="items.total = {}">
<tr>
  <td>name</td>
  <td>numberofyears</td>
  <td>amount</td>
  <td>intrest</td>
</tr>
<tr ng-repeat="item in items">
  <td>{{item.name}}</td>
  <td ng-init="items.total.numberofyears = items.total.numberofyears + item.numberofyears">{{item.numberofyears}}</td>
  <td ng-init="items.total.amount = items.total.amount + item.amount">{{item.amount}}</td>
  <td ng-init="items.total.interest = items.total.interest + item.interest">{{item.interest}}%</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>Total</td>
  <td>{{items.total.numberofyears}}</td>
  <td>{{items.total.amount}}</td>
  <td>{{items.total.interest}}%</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Do something like this:

HTML:

```
<table>
    <tr ng-repeat = "price in prices">
        <td ng-bind="price.price"><td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td ng-bind="calculateTotal()"><td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

JS:

```
$scope.prices = [{
  "price": "5"
}, {
  "price": "10"
}, {
  "price": "13"
}];


$scope.calculateTotal = function() {
  var total = 0;

  for (i = 0; i < $scope.prices.length; i++) {
    total += +$scope.prices[i].price; // (+) sign before variable is used to convert string values to number
  }

  return total;
};
```